# ¿Traducción de "strong" y "weak" con respecto el pulso de un compás musical?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, música

Por ejemplo, el segundo pulso de un compás es usualmente "weak" mientras el primero es "strong."

---

For example, the second beat of a measure is usually "weak" while the first is "strong"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una búsqueda rápida nos descubre muchos artículos de bastante fiabilidad que indican que la traducción por defecto parece la válida:

- *strong* → *fuerte*
- *weak* → *débil*

Por ejemplo en [Teoría musical - Lección 9: Tiempos fuertes y débiles](http://www.aprende-gratis.com/teoria-musical/curso.php?lec=tiempos-fuertes) se lee:

> No todos los tiempos son iguales. Existe un dinamismo entre ellos que hace que no todos suenen con la misma intensidad. Es decir, hay unos tiempos que suenan más fuertes que otros. De hecho, siempre e intuitivamente, al marcar un ritmo se refleja este dinamismo.
>
> Existen tres tipos de acentos:
>
> FUERTE - SEMIFUERTE - DÉBIL